# show that the system is controllable?

Tags: control-theory

Given that the LTV system $\dot x = A\left( t \right)x\left( t \right) + B\left( t \right)u\left( t \right)$ is controllable, how can I show that $\dot x = \left( {A\left( t \right) + B\left( t \right)K\left( t \right)} \right)x\left( t \right) + B\left( t \right)k\left( t \right)$ is controllable also?

my attempt: LTV system is controllable if the controllability Gramian has rank $n$ for all $t$. Obviously I have to use the fact that the nominal system is controllable but I do not seem to get any idea how to start. Any tips are appreciated!

Comment: Try working from the definition of controllable instead. Suppose $u^*$ steers $x_0$ to $x_1$ in the original system, can you find a law that (using $u^*$ in some way) that will steer the new system from $x_0$ to $x_1$?

Comment: @copper.hat I did thought about that actually. The definition of controllability for me is going from any state to the origin. I have that the original systems is controllable, i.e., $0{\text{ }} = {\text{ }}\Phi ({t_f},{\text{ }}{t_0}){x_0} + \int_{{t_0}}^{{t_f}} {\Phi (t,{\text{ }}\tau )B(\tau )u(\tau } )d\tau $ but if I replace new state matrix it gets messy...

Comment: @copper.hat especially since the state transition matrix is defined in term of integrals, that does not seem easy at all

Comment: You don't need to do that, You just need uniqueness of the solution of the ODE. If $u^*$ is a control law that steers the way you want, what will $k^* = u^*-Kx$ do to the new system?

Comment: @copper.hat ohh wow, I never though about it from that perspective, I guess $k*$ is the input to the new system which will steer it to desired state if I am not wrong

Comment: What differential equation does it solve?

Comment: @copper.hat if I plug $k^*$ in the second system I get the original system

Comment: And so the resulting solution will be the same as the original system with input $u^*$.

Comment: @copper.hat I think you already gave me the answer. if $u^*$ can steer original system to desired location, then $k^*$ steer the new system to desire location, am I right?

Comment: Informally you are just undoing the original feedback law. It is probably more instructive to look at it from this perspective.

Comment: @copper.hat perfect, thanks a lot! it was an easy trick, my mind went too far !!

Comment: @copper.hat I guess it is not trivial after all: given that $0{\text{ }} = {\text{ }}{\Phi _A}({t_f},{\text{ }}{t_0}){x_0} + \int_{{t_0}}^{{t_f}} {{\Phi _A}(t,{\text{ }}\tau )B(\tau ){u^*}(\tau } )d\tau $ I need to show that $0{\text{ }} = {\text{ }}{\Phi _{A + BK}}({t_f},{\text{ }}{t_0}){x_0} + \int_{{t_0}}^{{t_f}} {{\Phi _{A + BK}}(t,{\text{ }}\tau )\left( {{u^*}(\tau ) - Kx\left( \tau  \right)} \right)} d\tau $

Comment: Please do not delete your question when you have gotten so much help and feedback on it. Not only does it denigrate their efforts, it deprives others who may need the same question answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $\dot{x} = A(t)x+B(t)u$ is controllable on some interval $[t_0,t_1]$. I am interpreting this as meaning for any two states $x_0,x_1$ there is a control $u$ such that with $x(t_0) = x_0$ we end up with $x(t_1) = x_1$.

Now consider the system $\dot{y} = (A(t)+K(t)B(t))y+B(t)k$ with initial condition $y(t_0) = x_0$.
Choose the control $k = u-K(t) y$, then the resulting ODE is
$\dot{y} = A(t)y+B(t)u$ and hence $y(t) = x(t)$ for $t \in [t_0,t_1]$.
In particular, $y(t_1) = x_1$. Hence this system is controllable.

Comment: Why the downvote? Something wrong?